# Safely concatenating a SQL query

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-injection

I know, I know... There's no way to safely do this and I should always be using parameterized queries, but here's my situation.

I'm attempting to use Advanced Datagridview (https://github.com/davidegironi/advanceddatagridview) in a VB.Net forms application with a large dataset.  The gridview control has Excel like filtering that's quite nifty but the filtering is only done on the client side so I'd need to pull down the entire table to accurately filter.  This isn't practical so I need a way to pass the filtering to the server.  The control is able to generate a SQL-formatted string of it's current filter, such as:

```sql
([Plant] IN ('Argile - Chester', 'Bartlett - Riverton')) AND 
([VendorNum] IN ('1015')) AND 
([Qty] < 22.12)
```

So it would be quite easy just to concatenate that onto the query populating the grid view, but that would obviously be wide open to injection attacks.  Is there a way I can safely validate the string being supplied to check for any potential issues?  Or can anyone think of some other way of solving this problem given my constraints?

Only other option I can think of is doing away with the built-in filtering and just using form controls to set the filter values and pass those as parameters, but I really want to make use of the built-in filtering.  Another option would be to try and parse out the filter string the gridview generates and break it into individual fields to pass to parameters.  But there could potentially be several fields being filtered on and numerous values.  This would get dicey fast.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you mix the two: maybe one extra control to help pre-filter the data, so the larger grid has a reasonable size? Or maybe a `TOP n` added to the query, where you have some way to do a refresh if the filter changes too much. I don't remember what the code looked like, but I also worked on a product once with a grid control which could have 10's of thousands of items we bound to a datareader rather than a datatable, where it would only pull from the reader in chunks of 500, and not pull the next chunk until the user scrolled to the bottom.

Comment: There's no practical, safe way to do this. Code that generates arbitrary SQL can't be secured. Even if you had a reliable T-SQL parser (like Microsoft's own `TSqlParser`), which is a lot of overhead, you would still have to check the actual parse tree for any offending constructs, which is only slightly better then verifying the text. You could at least ensure this way the code does no more than (say) a single valid `SELECT`, but even that gives you no simple way to verify the code isn't selecting data it's not supposed to.

Comment: This is a double edged sword for sure. Leaving the obvious security problems out of the picture if you do all filtering on the server it means a full data refresh every single time you change the filter. If there is a lot of data this would be a huge time sink. This is also why most grids do client side filtering. You have to pull all the data only once and then filter it which greatly reduces the amount of traffic over the network.

Comment: I did not look at the code for this grid but I have used both Telerik and DevEx grids. Both of those have an event for column filtering that you can intercept. I have in the past utilized that event and queried the database based on the filter values found in the grid. I don't know if the tool you are using has that method exposed but might be worth exploring. Then you can easily parameterize your query which maintains prevention from sql injection and allows you to filter the data server side.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I looked into something similar and came up with a way to do paging to get the data in chunks.  It wasn't ideal because you'd eventually wind up pulling down the entire table even if there's nothing in the rest of the table you care about since SQL would have no idea what filtering you're using.  Keeping SQL aware of the filters really seemed like the best way to go.

Comment: I don't know what the string looks like but you can probably parse that into attributes and values. Then you can parameterize a query and bind the grid.

Comment: @SeanLange it has an event when the overall filter changes, but not when an individual column changes.  So while I can hook into the filter changing I'd still need some way to reliably parse out the different columns and values.  This may still be the best option, maybe I can write some regex to break the string apart

Comment: What if I run this concatenated query under a separate service account that only has select access to the necessary table, no ability to access any other table, ability to drop a table, etc.  Would that sufficiently mitigate the risk?

Comment: Can you not think of a way someone could commit mischief with only SELECT privilege?

Comment: Not when this service account can only do a select on this 1 table.  Am I missing anything else?

Comment: How about doing a `CROSS JOIN` 10 times, self-joining the same table on non-indexed columns, that'll generate a result set of the number of rows in the table raised to the 10th power. Then tack an `ORDER BY 1` at the end to force it to sort a few quadrillion rows. Bottom line: SQL injection is a real problem. Don't let untrusted input become part of an SQL query you execute.

Comment: Can you at least check that you a single `from [table]` and the table is same table as original query?

Comment: I think Bill's point here is there are potentially endless ways to compromise a system that allows injection and you can't assume you'll account for all of them.  His compounding join example was a clever one.  I was just thinking in terms of someone trying to access/alter data they shouldn't.  Performing a DoS would be just as bad.